# Responsive menu not working on iPad

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi guys [this](http://abiglittlebiz.com/trevelle) is my website if you test it on iPad the main menu is not working. All the main menu links are visible and and responsive menu button is also not working. I am really thankful who can help me to fix this issue

Comment: If you want help, please include what your code for your menu is, how it should behave and what is not working exactly. I looked at your website, but can't think of what you mean by "it's not working". Your site displays correctly, and the menu opens. Without the info on what should be behaving in an other way it is not possible to help you.

Comment: Sir  the problem occurs with iPad. if you are on firefox press ctrl+M and select iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Looked into it, seems like your menu button appears before your menu collapses in, therefore your have to either show the button at a smaller screen size or collapse the menu in on a bigger scrren size.

You probably set two different dependencies on the `@media`queries that show the button / collapse the menu. I unfortunally couldn't find the query that collapses your menu in/out, therefor i cannot provide you with a code change.